# In C# I can't get my XML to deserialize into an object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I've looked through the various questions on here similar to this, but can't get my solution to work.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community, building a WPF project.

I get xml from my backend API, and I'm trying to convert it into a C# object, but I can't get it to work.

This is the xml

```
<response>
    <computer_setting id="1" hospital_name="foo" computer_type="bar" environment="staging" label_printer_name="labels" document_printer_name="docs"/>
</response>
```

This is class

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Casechek.Kiosk
{
    [XmlRoot("response")]
    public class ComputerSettingResponse
    {
        [XmlElement("computer_setting")]
        internal ComputerSetting Settings { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ComputerSetting
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        internal string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("hospital_name")]
        internal string HospitalName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("computer_type")]
        internal string ComputerType { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("environment")]
        internal string Environment { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("label_printer_name")]
        internal string LabelPrinterName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("document_printer_name")]
        internal string DocumentPrinterName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my attempt to deserialize it

```
// Get ComputerSettings
String _Url = this.ApiUrl
   + "/api1/hospitals/foo/settings.xml"
   + "?access_token=" + Authentication.AccessToken;

XmlSerializer _Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ComputerSettingResponse));
ComputerSettingResponse _ComputerSettingResponse = new ComputerSettingResponse();
using (XmlTextReader _XmlReader = new XmlTextReader(_Url))
{
    _ComputerSettingResponse = (ComputerSettingResponse)_Serializer.Deserialize(_XmlReader);
    Debug.WriteLine(_ComputerSettingResponse.Settings.Environment);
}
```

But this throws NullReference exception when it gets to Debug.WriteLine()

{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

I've checked that the url is returning the xml properly, so it must me a poorly constructed class, or I'm not doing the deserialization properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your properties are required to be public in order to be serialised.  Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx):

> XML serialization is the process of converting an object's public properties and fields to a serial format (in this case, XML) for storage or transport.

Change `Settings` from `internal` to `public` and it will deserialise correctly (you will also have to change the class modified on `ComputerSetting` to `public` in order to compile).

As an aside, you shouldn't be using `XmlTextReader`, its use has been discouraged since .NET 2 was released.  Per the [remarks in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1af7xa52(v=vs.110).aspx), you should use `XmlReader.Create`.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has some nice tooling to generate serializable classes from XML or JSON - just copy a sample of your XML to the clipboard, open an empty class file and paste it as classes with the following menu path in Visual Studio: **Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as Classes** ...or, "Paste JSON as Classes" in the case of JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Once XDocument came out ( matched with Linq ) , I stopped all the Xml Attribute voodoo.  This "mapping" code is simple and straight forward.

```
public class ComputerSettingResponse
{
    internal ComputerSetting Settings { get; set; }
}

internal class ComputerSetting
{

    internal string Id { get; set; }

    internal string HospitalName { get; set; }

    internal string ComputerType { get; set; }

    internal string Environment { get; set; }

    internal string LabelPrinterName { get; set; }

    internal string DocumentPrinterName { get; set; }
}

            string xmlString = @"<response>
    <computer_setting id=""1"" hospital_name=""foo"" computer_type=""bar"" environment=""staging"" label_printer_name=""labels"" document_printer_name=""docs""/>
</response>          ";

        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

        //XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");
        string ns = string.Empty;


        List<ComputerSettingResponse> collection = new List<ComputerSettingResponse>
        (
            from list in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "response")
            from item1 in list.Elements(ns + "computer_setting")
            where item1 != null
            select new ComputerSettingResponse
            {
                //note that the cast is simpler to write than the null check in your code
                //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387049.aspx
                Settings = new ComputerSetting
                (
                ) 
                {
                    Id = (string)item1.Attribute("id") ?? string.Empty,
                    HospitalName = (string)item1.Attribute("hospital_name") ?? string.Empty,
                    ComputerType = (string)item1.Attribute("computer_type") ?? string.Empty,
                    Environment = (string)item1.Attribute("environment") ?? string.Empty,
                    LabelPrinterName = (string)item1.Attribute("label_printer_name") ?? string.Empty,
                    DocumentPrinterName = (string)item1.Attribute("document_printer_name") ?? string.Empty
                }
            }
        );

        /* if you know there is only one */
        ComputerSettingResponse returnItem = collection.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You can simplify all your attribute getters - e.g. `(string)item1.Attribute("id") ?? string.Empty`.  And `item1` will never be `null`.

Comment: Yep, that is noted in my comment near the url "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387049.aspx".  But thanks for providing real example code for the OP.

Comment: This solution lets you keep your "internal" designations.  Something to consider.

Answer (score 1):

In the above code you seem to treat "_Url" as XML but it's just the URL of the backend API, isn't it?

I tried replacing it with your sample XML and made it work only by changing the class visibility to **public**

So this worked for me:

```
        String xml = File.ReadAllText("XMLFile1.xml");
        XmlSerializer _Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ComputerSettingResponse));
        ComputerSettingResponse _ComputerSettingResponse = new ComputerSettingResponse();
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            _ComputerSettingResponse = (ComputerSettingResponse)_Serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            Debug.WriteLine(_ComputerSettingResponse.Settings.Environment);
        }
```

using the class like this:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Casechek.Kiosk
{
    [XmlRoot("response")]
    public class ComputerSettingResponse
    {
        [XmlElement("computer_setting")]
        public ComputerSetting Settings { get; set; }
    }

    public class ComputerSetting
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("hospital_name")]
        public string HospitalName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("computer_type")]
        public string ComputerType { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("environment")]
        public string Environment { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("label_printer_name")]
        public string LabelPrinterName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("document_printer_name")]
        public string DocumentPrinterName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I looked into why it didn't work with internal declaration and found this SO answer which helped me understand a few things about the internals of XmlSerializer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6156822/3093396

Hope this helps.